# Can't upload file greater than 2MB via PHP script

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have a form that asks the user to submit a photo. However, if the user tries to upload a file greater than 2MB, the results are emailed as expected but no photo is uploaded. While troubleshooting, I noted that I'm getting an error UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE.

I added the following to my php.ini, and verified with phpinfo() that the values are being loaded correctly.

```
upload_max_filesize = 34M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 320
memory_limit = 128M
```

Am I missing something? I've verified that a file sized at 1.4MB works fine, but a 4.2MB file fails.

Comment: restarted server after changes made?

Comment: make sure which php.ini file your server is using, something these settings can also be applied from apache

Comment: @Dagon - Yes, I've restarted the server a few times during troubleshooting, including after adding the code above to php.ini. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: @samaYo - Thanks, but I already checked the Loaded Configuration File in phpinfo() and verified that it's correct. Also, the values in phpinfo() for upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, etc. all change according to what I put in the php.ini I've been editing.

Comment: Are you using an upload script @WebDevKev maybe the upload script is checking `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000"/>` and giving you an error related to php

Comment: well `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` means that uploaded file is larger than `upload_max_filesize` but you say its not - so um? you or php is wrong - i'm picking you.

Comment: @samaYo - Nice thought, but I don't have any such line in the form.

Comment: @WebDevKev try https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof it's just one file, and using it takes 10 seconds. If it did not work, the the problem is def php

Comment: @Dagon - LOL! I'd bet against me, too, but I've verified all the numbers.

Comment: can we see the form in action? and add phpinfo() to the page

Comment: @Dagon - The form is at http://kentfeeds.com/show-feeds/show-awards/application/. I'm not crazy about sharing phpinfo() on here... Isn't that a little risky?

Comment: it shouldn't be. noting in it i can use to hack you (but i would say that)

Comment: @Dagon Just show us the code relevant to the upload ..

Comment: @samaYo ok give me a sec to hack his server.

Comment: @Dagon You scared him off :/

Comment: @samaYo :-) hope he finds a solution im out of ideas, there's only so much you can do with out direct access to the code

Comment: I think this is the relevant code: 

`if (!empty($_FILES["photo"])) {
 define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/home/kfeeds/public_html/images/show-winners/$year/");
 $photoFile = $_FILES["photo"];
 if ($photoFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  echo('Uh-oh!<br />');
  throw new UploadException($_FILES['photo']['error']);
  exit;
 }
`

Comment: @Dagon samaYo - Oh great! You two are now hacking my server, aren't you?! I _knew_ I shouldn't have shared so much!  =)

Comment: There seems nothing wrong to me with your configuration, I think the problem is with the script, even there seems nothing wrong with the relevant code, although it does not seem a well thought of script by the looks of it. Check the code I mentioned to upload a file, just to know if the script/php is causing the error. Also, I would do `var_dump($_FILES_);` in the middle of the script to see if I find something weird.

Comment: @samaYo - I added `var_dump($_FILES_);` before the `IF` statement in one of my previous comments. The result was "NULL".

Comment: @samaYo - Changed that to `var_dump($_FILES);` and got this: `array(1) { ["photo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "cow.jpg" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) } }`

Comment: Well, that's it .. size is `0` .. it should not be. even the mime type

Comment: Right... Because it fails to upload, right? Here's what I get with a (very) small image file: `array(1) { ["photo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "small.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpTYoooG" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(16193) } }`

Comment: Yeah, maybe there is a script changing the file_upload size somewhere .. can you echo `ini_get("upload_max_filesize");` inside your file upload script

Comment: @samaYo - Ooh! This confirmed my suspicion that it's a size limitation; `ini_get("upload_max_filesize");` yielded `2M`.

Comment: Well, make sure first in your scrip, if there is `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2M')` or something similar that is overdiing your php.ini setting

Comment: SOLVED! Thanks so much for your help @samaYo and Dagon!

Comment: @samayo your comment helped me solve my problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55913121/3904109

Comment: @DragonFire  I am glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the setting in WHM was overriding the php.ini file in my site's root directory. To fix it, I went to WHM, searched for PHP Configuration Editor, changed the upload_max_filesize to 32M, and clicked Save.

Thanks so much to @samaYo and @Dagan for helping me and eventually leading me in the right direction to get it solved!